# jQuery Mobile - Listview only loads on second page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a small jQuery Mobile application. I have a home page with a banner image, a paragraph loaded from a json file, and a link to a second page that has a linked list, also loaded from the json file.

The home page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BikeShare</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <style>
            #banner {
                height: 175px;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: relative;
            }
            #banner img {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;
                max-width: 100%;
            }
            .bold {
                font-weight: bold;
                border-bottom: 1px dotted;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function getLocations(data) {
                var locations = data.stationBeanList;
                var numLocations = 0;
                var numBikes = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                    if (locations[i].statusValue === 'In Service' && locations[i].availableBikes > 0) {
                        numBikes += locations[i].availableBikes;
                        numLocations++;
                    }
                }
                var message = '<p>There are a total of <span class="bold">' + numBikes + ' bikes</span> available in <span class="bold">' + numLocations + ' locations</span>.</p>';
                $("#home-content-heading").after(message);
            }

            $(document).on("pagecreate", "#home", function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "bikeshare.json",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: getLocations,
                    error: function() { console.log( 'Error...' ); }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b" id="main-nav">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="reports.html">Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="locations.html">Locations</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="home-header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Home</h1>
                <a href="#main-nav" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-bars">Menu</a>
            </div>
            <div id="banner"><img src="bicycle-rental-dock.jpg" alt="A bicycle rental dock" /></div>
            <div role="main" id="home-content" class="ui-content">
                <h1 id="home-content-heading">BikeShare</h1>
                <a href="locations.html" class="ui-btn ui-shadow" data-transition="slide">View Locations</a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
                <h4>&copy; 2015 BikeShare</h4>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end #home -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The second page with the linked list:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BikeShare</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
        <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on("pagecreate", "#locations", function() {
                function loadData(data) {
                    var locations = data.stationBeanList;
                    var list = '';
                    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                        list += '<li><a href="">' + locations[i].stationName + '</a></li>';
                    }
                    $("#location-list").append(list).listview('refresh');
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: "bikeshare.json",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: loadData,
                    error: function() { console.log('Failed to load bikeshare.json'); }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="locations">
            <div data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" data-theme="b" id="main-nav">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="reports.html">Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Locations</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Locations</h1>
                <a href="#main-nav" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-bars">Menu</a>
            </div>
            <div role="main" class="ui-content">
                <ul id="location-list" data-role="listview"></ul>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
                <h4>&copy; 2015 BikeShare</h4>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end #locations -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The issue I'm having is when I click on the link and go to the second page, the listview (from json file) does not display unless I hit the browser refresh button. And if I hit refresh and then hit the browser back button, the banner on the first page does not have the custom css applied to it, in addition, the data that was previously loaded and displayed from the json file, it's no longer there. I do not see where I went wrong with my code. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile by default loads external pages via ajax into the current page's DOM. However, it only loads the markup of the first DIV with data-role="page".

So, you can move the locations javascript into the data-role="page" DIV.

If you don't like the AJAX navigation system, you can 'turn it off', but then you lose the nice transitions.

Read this:  http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/

Comment: Thanks, I had to turn off the ajax using data-ajax="false" to get it to work.